# IOS: How to disable the user_session in the HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, http, oauth

I'm working on supporting login by Github OAuth. But I encounter a problem:

When I log in to the Github once, the subsequence OAuth requests will fail with the 302 HTTP status.

When the OAuth request failed, the HTTP request is as follow:

[image]

The HTTP response is as follow:

[image]

I know the 302 response is caused by the "user_session" in the HTTP request.

My question is that is there any way to disable the user_sesion in the HTTP request. I want to send a totally new HTTP request for each OAuth request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution at [Disabling cookies in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559340/disabling-cookies-in-wkwebview). But it doesn't work for me.

After using 
`myRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = false`

The WKWebView stops working. I guess it may be caused by the server cannot add cookies to our web browser.

The solution described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31803708/10399490 works for me.

Just remove the cookies added by the Github.

**I haven't verified whether the solution introduces any other side effects**