# How to disable cookies on all requests in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

I'm trying to completely disable all handling of cookies in a `WKWebView`.

There's a straightforward way to disable cookies for the *initial* request to load a page (see [Disabling cookies in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559340/disabling-cookies-in-wkwebview)):

```swift
let url = URL(string: "http://example.org")!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
webView.load(urlRequest)
```

But any subsequent requests performed by the web view (e.g. when the user clicks on a link to navigate to another page) do include cookies. Inspecting the HTTP traffic generated by the web view shows that the `Cookie` header is being set on those requests, which is the behaviour I'd like to disable.

Clearing the contents of `WKWebsiteDataStore` or the `WKHTTPCookieStore` has no effect either as these transient cookies do not appear in the store when using a `nonPersistent` store.

Is there any mechanism for stopping cookies to be included for all requests in the `WKWebView` on iOS?

Comment: `httpShouldHandleCookies` doesn't disable cookies, it simply overrides default handling of the cookies for that particular request. I don't know if there's a direct way to actually _disable_ cookies - I haven't heard. One workaround would be via `WKHTTPCookieStore`, where you can register `WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver` and delete cookie as soon as you were notified that it was added...

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem this is supported for WKWebView, see also https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/16847.